# PMD - Is there a way to track PMD complaince by individual developer

Tags: java, findbugs, pmd

Is there a tool or plugin to track PMD, CheckStyle & Findbugs noncompliance report for each developer

Thanks
KR

Answer (score 3):

Seems that [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) is what you need

> Sonar is an open source quality
>   management platform, dedicated to
>   continuously analyze and measure
>   technical quality

it has different additional [plugins](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Sonar+Plugin+Library/), but by default it has all that you need - checkstyle, pmd, findbugs. All that you need is just download, unpack it somewhere, start sonar. For your project you need minimal pom.xml (sonar uses it to know where compiled files are), and you execute you pom with command (as I do):

mvn clean compile sonar:sonar

Read more on [documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Documentation) page of sonar project.

There is also a way to integrate [Sonar with Eclipse](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Sonar+Eclipse) (but you need to have Sonar, Eclipse just will connect to it and get reports, anyway it is easy to use because you open class and see sonar remarks related to it, so you can fix them)

[Here](http://nemo.sonarsource.org/) are sonar reports in action, you can try and decide ;)

Comment: It won't generate any kind of general "Who made what" report, but combined with the "blame" plugin, it's easy to find the information for each violation. +1

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of such a tool, but I think it would be technically feasible to write one, given the time.

Hypothetically, such a tool would need to work by checking out each and every revision from version control, run the PMD / CheckStyle / FindBugs on each revision, and then ascribe the "deltas" in the reported violations to the person who checked in the revision.

However, I suspect that using a tool like could have serious downsides.

Firstly, such a tool doesn't actually improve code quality, or even quantify your code quality problems any better than you can already do.  All it does it is to "point the finger of blame" at individual team members.

And it could well be that the finger pointing is unfair.  For instance, it is a fact that PMD and FindBugs often flag things as violations when they are clearly harmless, or a matter of considerable debate.   When someone on your team who gets "dinged" for introducing such violations, they are going to be justifiably aggrieved.

If you are not careful, the net result will be loss of team morale, and team members focusing on violation counts instead of working to progress the project.

Similarly, you shouldn't use reports from such a tool to figure out who your best / worst developers are.  You are likely to get the wrong answer.

Comment: Hi Stephen, You are very true and I perfectly get that point. Ofcourse this not to pinpoint someone rather trying to improve someone. I know its challenging but we wanted to given an attempt.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a version control system, you can use the blame/praise function which will show you line-by-line which develper last touched it. If you are using a good IDE it should be able to annotate your gutter/margin with the information.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. TO give you more clarity on the requirement, as we would see statistics in hudson dashboard using plugins how many PMD, Findbug, etc issues we have, the similar way I like to have a tool like this... Person A - PMD violations 15, Findbug Violations 20, Person B - - PMD violations 5, Findbug Violations 17 like that.